# How to host many SNI certificates in Nginx

Tags: nginx, cname, sni

My company's product allows our users to custom brand by picking a personal subdomain.  We handle this with a wildcard match in nginx and then let Rails decide what to do.  We require SSL everywhere and have a wildcard SSL cert, so this all works beautifully.

Now we'd like to offer custom CNAMEs, with SSL, as an add-on feature.  Since we don't really want to provision hundreds of IP addresses, we'll use SNI and accept the caveats.  What's the best way to setup nginx with all of these certs?  We could either allow users to upload their own cert, or we could buy them for the user.  Either way, how do we make nginx see them and serve them without restarts and on a large scale?  Can nginx read it's config dynamically from mysql somehow, read the certificate from a script, or pass the certificate responsibility to Rails?  Ideas welcome!

Comment: Andrew, did you ever implement this?

Comment: No, we didn't end up building it.